# Why is Corona not reloading the scene?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I try to make a card game that will change scenes when the player touches on the card but the initial page does not load again.
My code follows:

main.lua

```
local storyboard = require("storyboard")
local background = display.newImage("Icon-72.png")
storyboard.gotoScene("level1")
```

level1.lua

```
local storyboard = require("storyboard")
local level1 = storyboard.newScene()

function level1:createScene( event )
    print("level 1 create scene")
    local group = self.view
    local x = 3
    group:insert(display.newText(x,40,50))
    -- body

    local card = display.newImage("Icon-Small.png")
    card.x = 50 ; card.y = 150
    group:insert(card)
    function card:touch(event )
        display.remove(card)
        storyboard.gotoScene("level2")
    end

    card:addEventListener("touch",card)
  end

function level1:enterScene( event )
    local group = self.view
    local card = display.newImage("Icon-Small.png")
    card.x = 50 ; card.y = 150
    group:insert(card)
    function card:touch(event )
        display.remove(card)
        storyboard.gotoScene("level2")
    end

    card:addEventListener("touch",card)
    -- body
  end
level1:addEventListener("createScene",level1)
level1:addEventListener("enterScene",level1)
return level1
```

level 2 :

```
local storyboard = require("storyboard")
local level2 = storyboard.newScene()

function level2:createScene( event )
    print("level2 create")
    local group = self.view
    storyboard.purgeScene("level1")
    storyboard.gotoScene("level1")
end
level2:addEventLister("createScene",level2)
return level2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo at the bottom of level2.lua:

```
level2:addEventLister("createScene",level2)
```

Should be:

```
level2:addEventListener("createScene",level2)
```

Comment: is print("level2 create") called ?

Comment: yeap..it is called, and then it does go back to level 1 but it won't show the clickable image again...

Comment: Also, what you are doing at the moment is that you create the card twice on the first scene... Calling purge on scene level1 means that when we go again to the level1 scene it will call both createScene / enterScene... Is that what you would like to do ? Probably not considering that the cards are created with same x and y and same icon ?

Comment: Also I don't think you need display.remove(card) in the card:touch handlers because the card is linked to the scene group anyway so it will automatically get removed when the next scene loads.